# How to lockdown a computer for use in a public area?

Tags: windows-7, virus, kiosk, multiple-users

So I live in an apartment complex with a few hundred people. There are two all-in-one windows 7 PCs in the lobby for residents to use. Oddly enough they keep mysteriously getting infected with viruses and breaking (hint: sarcasm).

My friend works in the office and I want to help. The IT guy they hired obviously doesn't know what to do because he thinks the hard drives or motherboards are broken; they're relatively new computers and they have locks on the case so nobody could have broken those parts. It's probably just some viruses or crap the residents downloaded; the computers just keep freezing in recovery screens and restarting.

I'm going to just format the hard drives and reinstall Windows because that's the obvious thing to do (not so obvious for the 'IT guy').

My question is what's a good way to limit the things that the public can do on the computers so that they can't download and run malware or viruses. I've heard of kiosk programs, but I'm not sure how those will work for this situation.

It would be nice for them to still have the permission to download and edit documents and use the internet as they are all college students. If anyone has recommendations for what to do to prevent this from happening again (this isn't the first time) that would be great.

---

P.S. I'd have much rather just installed Linux, it's a lot harder to screw that up if you limit all the permissions and require a sudo password for everything outside of a public desktop folder or something like that. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to

Comment: Feel free to use the [edit link](http://superuser.com/posts/1000968/edit) to add this sort of information to your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an admin and a regular account on the PC's and go to set UAC to maximum.

EDIT 1:
You could also take a look at the group policy editor (you can launch it from Windows-key + R and type gpedit.msc). Or use a program like DeepFreeze (DeepFreeze costs money but I am sure that there are free programs that do the same). DeepFreeze basically resets the computer if it restarts.

Comment: Also install a highly rated (possibly free) anti-malware suite, e.g. Avast!, Kaspersky etc, and image a *known good* disk, and restore from the image -- faster and safer than trying to remove malware.

Comment: Ok, so that will prevent them from installing programs? or will it just warn them? I'll try it.

Comment: If you set UAC to max. it will require the admin password to install prgrams

Comment: @griffinc It may be worth you checking this out to see if it'd suffice for the need GP configuration wise. Having these in some sort of "steady state" would probably be best (like an image) or have an easy way to revert quickly to the state it previously was in after you reinstall, configure, etc. https://blogs.windows.com/itpro/2010/09/27/steady-state-for-windows-7. . .  Just another idea of a way to help potentially but AV and anti-malware that's fully updated definition wise would be best too. All the common sense type stuff.

Comment: UAC is probably the way to go, I tried looking for alternatives to DeepFreeze, Windows SteadyState was discontinued says Wikipedia :(

Comment: @griffinc Read the links though in that article (they point to Technet and other MS sites), it shows you which GP settings, etc. to set to assist with locking it down like Steady State... They didn't set it up for Windows 7 as Windows 7 aparently has built-in functionality that accomplishes the same thing... It should help along with the other common sense type stuff so everytime it happens you're not spending hours rebuilding a kiosk machine from scratch... Good luck with it for sure!! Base it off of what MS says, not Wikipedia...